# How do I set up hunspell on a Windows PC?

Tags: microsoft-windows, hunspell

I have my hunspell dictionaries at `C:\hunspell\`. It contains `.dic` and `.aff` files for three languages: `en_GB`, `en_US`, and `nb_NO`. The descriptions I find on the web about how to make hunspell work in Emacs make me confused.

What is the minimum code I need in my init file to be able to use these three hunspell dictionaries in Emacs?

I have tried the following code suggested by one web site:

```el
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/hunspell/bin/")
(setq ispell-program-name (locate-file "hunspell"
                       exec-path exec-suffixes 'file-executable-p))
```

But when wanting to change dictionary by `M-x ispell-change-dictionary`, I get the following message:

> ispell-phaf: No matching entry for nil.

Comment: Related: [Make hunspell work with emacs and german language](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86554/30580).

Comment: As well as https://stackoverflow.com/q/56429761/1661465

Answer (score 7):

Emacs setup:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "c:/what-ever-path/hunspell")

;; "en_US" is key to lookup in `ispell-local-dictionary-alist'.
;; Please note it will be passed as default value to hunspell CLI `-d` option
;; if you don't manually setup `-d` in `ispell-local-dictionary-alist`
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US") 

(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)))

;; new variable `ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist' is defined in Emacs
;; If it's nil, Emacs tries to automatically set up the dictionaries.
(when (boundp 'ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist)
  (setq ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist ispell-local-dictionary-alist))

;; With Emacs 28.2 may also need to set hunspell-default-dict
(setq hunspell-default-dict "en_US")
```

Hunspell dictionary setup:

Run `hunspell -D` in dos window which will list the directories hunspell searching for dictionaries. Copy your dictionaries to that directory. This is the minimum setup you need.

See http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html for more technical details.

Comment: Worked for me! My setup with `use-package` is `(use-package ispell
  :config
  (setq ispell-program-name "C:/Program Files (x86)/hunspell-1.3.2-3-w32-bin/bin/hunspell.exe")
  (setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US") 
  (setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8))))`

Comment: Just do (setq ispell-program-name "c:/what-ever-path/hunspell.exe") in Windows 10 for hunspell without other configuration works for English spelling check.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem myself a while back. If I recall correctly, the reason you get that error message is because `hunspell` is unable to configure itself based on the current environment. So to fix it, you need to configure the `hunspell` specific `ispell` variables. The following code *should* be enough to setup hunspell for english dictionaries:

```
(require 'flyspell)
(setq ispell-dictionary "english")
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '(("english"
                                               "[[:alpha:]]"
                                               "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                               "[']"
                                               t
                                               ("-d" "en_US")
                                               nil
                                               utf-8)))
(setq ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist ispell-local-dictionary-alist)
```

The important part is the `ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist`, it has to be populated with a proper dictionary list, such as the one given in `ispell-local-dictionary-alist`.

There's quite a bit of details surrounding this list though. If you want to know more about it, feel free to read up with `M-x describe-variable` `ispell-local-dictionary-alist`.

Comment: +1 there seems to be something wrong with the default attempt to populate the `ispell-hunspel-dictionary-alist`.  Instead of `(require 'flyspell)` you might consider `(with-eval-after-load "ispell" ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Install all the dictionaries you want in the location that hunspell searches in; find this with `hunspell -D`. Once installed, this command should show them.

In the init file, add just add one of them E.g. I have `en_GB` and `en_US` dictionaries installed. I've, in my init file, this:

```
(setenv "DICTIONARY" "en_GB")
```

Upon opening Emacs, just enable `flyspell-mode`. Emacs should say that it is started ispell with default dictionary. This means `en_GB` is in action, for our example. Now if you want to switch, just do `M-x ispell-change-dictionary` and give the new dictionary name E.g. `en_US`. Now the other dictionary should be in action. This, again, will be notified by Emacs saying it started ispell but this time with the `en_US` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using a recent version of Emacs (24.4 or above, as I recall) then all you need to do is make sure you're using the correct dictionary name, and Emacs will do the rest automatically.

The main problem is that Windows uses a different language description format, for example British English is called **ENG**, and US English is **ENU**. This means your dictionary files should be called *ENU.dic* and *ENU.aff* for US English, and *ENG.dic* and *ENG.aff* for British English.

It may also be necessary to have a "default" dictionary or hunspell may not be too happy. You can also set the *DICTIONARY* environment variable to force a default.

Unfortunately I can't work out what your Norwegian dictionary should be called. If you're using the Norwegian locale in Windows, you should be able to check within Emacs by evaluating:

```
(getenv "LANG")
```

Which will show you the setting that Emacs is using.

Answer (score 1):

chen bin and serghei's answer worked for me on Emacs 26.x, but not with Emacs 27.1, which seems to have an updated ispell.el file. In Emacs 27.1, I would get:

```
Can’t find Hunspell dictionary with a .aff affix file
```

To "fix", I overwrote ./share/emacs/27.1/lisp/textmodes/ispell.el with a version from 26.x.

Comment: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/22240/17463 and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18195/17463 make sure to set the ispell-hunspell-dictionary-alist variable

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but maybe you need to tell which language you would
like to use as the “default”:

```el
(setq ispell-dictionary "en") ; default dictionary
```

Default value of `ispell-dictionary` is `nil`, so may be this is the cause
of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark, for your tip, but unfortunately it does not seem to change my situation. The error message still pops up