# Greek typing & spell-checking with hunspell: encoding issue?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, input-method, hunspell

`hunspell`-checking Greek text I create in Emacs is not working.

Notes:

- I am aware of this post: [Spell check with multiple dictionaries](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21378/spell-check-with-multiple-dictionaries)
- Eventually, I want to use `ispell` with `hunspell` in Emacs, which is also currently not working, I guess due to the problem described below.

Let me show my setup so far:

I downloaded a Greek dictionary from this page,
https://sourceforge.net/projects/orthos-spell/files/v.0.4.0./orthos-el_GR-0.4.0-87.oxt/download,
and extracted and installed the 2 relevant files:

```
$ unzip -x orthos-el_GR-0.4.0-87.oxt dicts/el_GR.dic dicts/el_GR.aff          
$ sudo mv * /usr/share/hunspell/

$ hunspell -D
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
...
/usr/share/hunspell/el_GR
...
Hunspell 1.3.2
```

For testing on the command line, I copied and pasted a word from the dictionary `/usr/share/hunspell/el_GR.dic`. Spell checking works fine.

```
$ echo "άλφα" | hunspell -d el_GR 
Hunspell 1.3.2
*
```

Now to Emacs: First I set the input method to `greek-babel`.

```
M-x set-input-method greek-babel
```

Now I can type `alfa` (the `ά` I get by `'` followed by `a`):

```
άλφα
```

But pasting this into the `hunspell` commandline call, the word `alfa` with this accented `a` is not recognized:

```
$ echo "άλφα" | hunspell -d el_GR 
Hunspell 1.3.2
& άλφα 1 0: άλφα
```

A quick test in `python` shows that the accented `a`s are different characters:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 03 2017, 17:41:54) [GCC] on linux2
> ['ά'], ['ά']
(['\xce\xac'], ['\xe1\xbd\xb1'])
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What character encoding are you using in Emacs?

Comment: C-h v buffer-file-coding-system shows utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basil above hit the spot! Thanks for the detailed explanation.

This solved the issue for me:

```
M-x set-input-method greek
```

I then consulted the input method docs with

```
M-x describe-input-method
```

to find, how to add the acute and diaeresis symbols to characters (: and ; keys).

The greek text is now perfectly real-time spell-checked through flyspell.

Next I'll implement programmatic dictionary switching.

Thanks again
Dave

Comment: Note that, by default, `toggle-input-method` and `set-input-method` are bound to `C-\ ` and `C-x RET C-\ `, respectively, and `describe-input-method` is bound to `C-h I`. You can also accept your own answer if your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I know very little about spellcheckers, Unicode, and Emacs input methods and encodings; the following is just my superficial hunch as a native Greek speaker.

Unicode defines different code points for `?ά` (`U+03AC GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH TONOS`) and the visually very similar, if not identical, `?ά` (`U+1F71 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA WITH OXIA`), as explained in the following articles:

- https://wiki.digitalclassicist.org/Greek_Unicode_duplicated_vowels
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_diacritics#Unicode
- https://www.unicode.org/faq/greek.html

The articles also explain the various historical reasons for this discrepancy/duality. The crux of the matter is that all three Classical Greek input methods in Emacs (`greek-babel`, `greek-ibycus4`, and `greek-mizuochi`) use the *oxia* variant, whereas the two Modern Greek input methods (`greek` and `greek-postfix`) use the more conventional *tonos* variant.

So my guess is that some part of your spellchecker stack fails to "fold" the characters with *oxia* and *tonos* as comprising the same word.

Unless you need to write polytonic Classical Greek, I recommend you use the monotonic Modern Greek input method `greek`, rather than `greek-babel`.

I'm not sure whether the relevant input methods could handle this better, e.g. by using the more conventional *tonos* variants together with combining characters for the other polytonic accents, but I might raise this question on the `bug-gnu-emacs` or `emacs-devel` mailing lists after looking into the subject a bit more (feel free to do so yourself in the meantime).