# How to install multiple dictionaries in Emacs?

Tags: hunspell

I am using Emacs 26.1 on MacOS 10.14.2. I am trying to use `hunspell` with 3 dictionaries that are installed in `~/Library/Spelling` but when I start Emacs I got the following error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`

```
;; Portuguese dictionary
 (with-eval-after-load "ispell"
   (setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
   (setq ispell-dictionary "en_GB,en_US,pt_PT")
;;   ispell-set-spellchecker-params has to be called
;;   before ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic will work
   (ispell-set-spellchecker-params)
   (ispell-hunspell-add-multi-dic "en_GB,en_US,pt_PT"))
```

Comment: It seems that you have an error in your init file, my guess is that it's the call to `ispell-set-spellchecker-params`, which probably takes some arguments. You could try commenting out different expressions to pin down the problem.

Comment: I commented out the last 2 lines and Emacs starts with no error. But I have no spell checking. I don't know what parameters I am missing after `ispell-set-spellchecker-params`. I followed the answer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21378/spell-check-with-multiple-dictionaries.

Comment: What steps have you taken to configure `hunspell` to look in `~/Library/Spelling`?  I don't use `hunspell`, but perhaps there is a `conf` file (that either exists already, or can be created in the right location) where a user may specify the path of a dictionary location if it is different than what was specified (or the default) when the program was built.

Comment: Well I tried to configure `hunspell` with the following: ```(setenv
  "DICPATH"
  (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Library/Spelling"))``` but I got an init error.