# Ispell does not seem to use hunspell

Tags: doom, ispell, hunspell, setq

I tried to set up ispell to use hunspell with [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51342/hunspell-not-working).

but it seems like ispell is still not using hunspell.

Ispell in Emacs would mark this word as wrong: `Schulwochen` (German)

```
$ hunspell -d de_DE
Hunspell 1.7.0
Schulwochen
-
```

So I guess ispell is nor using hunspell.
Since other German word appear correct in emacs ispell, I am pretty sure ispell is using a German dictionary.

### config.el

```
[...]
(setq ispell-program-name (executable-find "/usr/bin/hunspell")
      ispell-dictionary   "de_DE")
```

### init.el

```
[...]
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "de_DE")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("de_DE" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)))
```

OS: Fedora
Emacs: Doom

```
~> ispell -vv
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.8)
~> hunspell -vv
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.2.06 (but really Hunspell 1.7.0)
```

This might be the problem but I could not find a way to update ispell.

Comment: What does `C-h v ispell-program-name` say?

Comment: Your right. Something did not work. `Value "aspell"`

Comment: The given code is: `  (or (executable-find "enchant-2")
      (executable-find "hunspell")
      (executable-find "aspell")
      (executable-find "ispell")
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to your init file:

```el
(eval-after-load 'ispell
    (setq ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell")
          ispell-dictionary   "de_DE"))
```

and check with `C-h v ispell-program-name` after you restart emacs.

This should make sure that you get the final word on setting `ispell-program-name`.

Comment: The Value is still aspell. I made sure that "exe-path" was correct and my emacs installation was no flatpak, but still emacs seem unable to find hunspell and enchant-2

Comment: Can you uninstall `aspell` temporarily? If that is feasible, you can start emacs and see if it finds `hunspell` instead.

Comment: This worked. Its now using hunspell. Could you add this to your answer and I check it.

Comment: Will do - it's a half-measure however so I want to do some testing first and then think about how to phrase it.